# here, I created _inputfields Widget for the text fields and I just want to remove underlines from the text fields but it doesn't allow me to do that

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout, textfield

```
              _inputfields(context,"Username",_userName.focusNode,                 
                           _userName.mycontroller,false),

              _inputfields(context, "Password", _password.focusNode,
                           _password.mycontroller, true),
```

...........

Widget _inputfields(BuildContext context, String hinttext, FocusNode _focusnode,
TextEditingController _controller, bool obscure,
{bool optional = false}) {
return Container(
decoration:  BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.purple,

```
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),


),
```

Comment: It shows "InputDecoration Can not be assigned to the "Decoration" parameter

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a **TextStyle** without an underline like so:

```
TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none);
```

Now Assuming you are using a **TextFormField**:

```
    TextFormField(style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your sample Username'), 

                  validator: (input) { return null;});
```